# How to Click on Enter in Keypad using AndroidDriver<MobileElement>?

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I am trying to automate some basic functionalities of Mobile App.

**Use Case:** Click on Search Item; Provide your search item name; Click on Keypad Enter to trigger the Search.

I am using AndroidDriver as my driver.
I tried below code:

```
Option 1: driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.ENTER));
Option 2: driver.pressKey(new KeyEvent(AndroidKey.SEARCH));
Option 3: driver.findElement(<SearchElement>).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);**
```

I am using Appium Java Client (7.3.0)

All other keys like SPACE,A,B, other alphabets and numbers are working using AndroidKey except ENTER.

Please provide some support.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android native key events to get this done:

```
 AndroidDriver driver;
 driver.pressKeyCode(66);
```

The keycode `66` is to trigger `Enter` key in Android.